# Not able to retrieve the user profile properties of farm admin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-property

I have a user login `sharepointadmin` as farm administrator. The user profile properties for `DOMAIN/sharepointadmin` is also configured.

I am not able to retrieve the user profile properties for `sharepointadmin` user alone while I can retrieve the user profile properties for other AD users.

Do I have to make any changes in settings of `sharepointadmin` user so as to make his user profile properties retrievable? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How do you try to get the profile properties? Do you get an error message?

Comment: No i din't get any error message.Exactly my scenario is , I have a list containing bunch of Cafe menu items for each location which will be retrieved and showed in webpart based on current user's office location. I'm able to view the menu items if i use my AD credentials.But If I use sharepoint admins credentials i dint get any items in my webpart though the location property of sharepointadmin is correct.